# How to properly work with Admod when app publishing

Tags: java, android, google-play, admob, google-play-console

when I publishing app in testing version I use admob with test id.
Application passes UI tests by bot,respectively bot clicks on admob add.
If I use real admob id when I publishing app in relese , my admob account is will banned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will most likely be the case and even if it isn't, google will stop serving ads to anywhere the bot can access so it is pointless to this.

Comment: @Osman Google is smart enough to implement these measures to keep malicious users away.

Comment: Thanks.I'll go and try it. I just don't want to risk it